# Dedicated book to understand climate and ocean science

Tags: climate, oceanography, earth-system, reference-request

Let me explain: I am a physics student who did some basic earth science during my early high school days. But thinking about earth science makes me very curious about deeper topics, like how the oceans were formed, why the oceans are saline, how salinity of the oceans affects the climate pattern around the world and how weather patterns are altered by bio-geochemical changes.

I have used Google to search for answers to such questions and had mixed success. So now I want to dive deeper into earth science with a dedicated book. I tried approaching Google for this, but the results were confusing.

I would like to get some of the most trusted books on earth and climate science.

Sorry if this question does not fit in prescribed pattern of the site.

Comment: If moderator can listen to my text, I have a complaint there is a frequent negative vote to my question without giving reason

Comment: Which confuse me to what actually goes wrong in the question so I request them either undo it or give the reasoning thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

there are very different books on this topic. Therefore, a concrete selection is somewhat more complex.

But to gain a good insight into biogeochemical processes, I would recommend the book:

Biogeochemistry An Analysis of Global Change 4th Edition - August 7, 2020. But at 80 euros, it's not cheap at all. But it explains perfectly how biogeochemical cycles work on earth and how they change with climate change. This is my personal favourite on the subject of biogeochemistry.

[image]

However, if you want to learn about the formation of oceans, I would recommend the book: Earth System History by Steven M. Stanley et al. In this book you will find the history of the earth broken down very well in my opinion.

[image]

And a third book that fits your question well and that I like to use is the book: Torsvik, T.H., Cocks, R.M. (2017) Earth History and Palaeogeography. The title is self-explanatory.

[image]

You may see that it is very difficult to find only one book, but these are three books that can be read well with different levels of knowledge. This means that you as a non-expert reader can learn just as much as a reader who has studied the subject.

But if you need something more specific, post it in the comments and I'll see what I can recommend. More specific topics include how ocean currents have shifted due to climate change or the role of oceans in the Earth system.